# Por que o resultado do RegEx possui dois valores?

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso de padrões de kb, mb ou gb, estou utilizando a expressão regular `(k|m|g)b$` e tem que estar no final da linha.

O [teste da minha expressão](https://regex101.com/) resulta em **somente 1 match** quando testo "20kb", porém nesse script o array possui 2 posições. Por que isso ocorre?

Script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="p01">The best things in life are free!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    text = document.getElementById("p01").innerHTML; 
var re = "(k|m|g)b$";
var str = "20kb".trim().toLowerCase();
var myArray = str.match(re);
console.log(myArray);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myArray;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quando você inclui expressões entre parênteses, você forma um **grupo de captura**, sinalizando que está interessada não só no casamento como um todo mas também naquele trecho em particular. O resultado então traz na primeira posição a string inteira casada, e em cada posição subsequente os grupos de captura na ordem em que foram definidos.

Para fazer com que um grupo não seja de captura, use `(?:...)`:

```
(?:k|m|g)b$
```

Comment: alternativamente `[kmg]b$` ?